# Visual studio doesn't run xamarin forms project

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms in visual studio and whenever I start my project, it builds but doesn't actually run. It doesn't even run the android emulator.

Comment: You haven't included any useful information we could use to help you.  You haven't even asked a proper question.  Have you looked in the logs?  Checked the application output window?  Looked for crashes?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it

Comment: @Jason how did you solve?